# John the ripper not able to crack the password

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, john-the-ripper, wordlist

I generated two hashes from [this](https://www.symbionts.de/tools/hash/sha256-hash-salt-generator.html) site:

Plaintext 1 (p1): `world` 
Salt 1 (s1): `hello` 
Hash 1 (h1): `936a185caaa266bb9cbe981e9e05cb78cd732b0b3280eb944412bb6f8f8f07af` 

Plaintext 2 (p2): `world2` 
Salt 2 (s2): `hello2` 
Hash 2 (h2): `36d357c14829ba5bcb75d33c4edd3b7691fece0317ff898ce9709fb6911c9ab9` 

This is the content of hash.txt:

```
username:936a185caaa266bb9cbe981e9e05cb78cd732b0b3280eb944412bb6f8f8f07af$hello
username2:36d357c14829ba5bcb75d33c4edd3b7691fece0317ff898ce9709fb6911c9ab9$hello2
```

This is the content of dummy_wordlist.txt:

```
world
world2
world3
```

I use the command:

```
john --format=dynamic_61 --wordlist dummy_wordlist.txt hash.txt
```

Output is:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> john --format=dynamic_61 --wordlist dummy_wordlist.txt hash.txt
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 2 password hashes with 2 different salts (dynamic_61 [sha256($s.$p) 256/256 AVX2 8x])
Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=12
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
world            (username)
1g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2021-09-11 13:28) 333.3g/s 1182Kp/s 2302Kc/s 2302KC/s Hammer..sss
Use the "--show --format=dynamic_61" options to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
Session completed
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop>
```

However, on checking the cracked passwords, only one of them is visible:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> john --show --format=dynamic_61 .\hash.txt
username:world

1 password hash cracked, 1 left
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The output shows that it is trying the words `Hammer..sss`, which are not in your wordlist.  I'd double-check that it is using your wordlist and not a default list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax to specify the wordlist.  There should be an equals sign `=` between `--wordlist` and the name of the wordlist.

Wrong:
`john --format=dynamic_61 --wordlist dummy_wordlist.txt hash.txt`

Correct:
`john --format=dynamic_61 --wordlist=dummy_wordlist.txt hash.txt`